# Vue-router doesn't redirect with @click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Template:

```
<button @click="redirect">Search</button>
<input v-model="searchQuery" v-on:keyup.enter="redirect" type="text">
```

Js script:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    redirect: function() {
      if (this.searchQuery) {
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'tag',
          params: {
            tag: this.searchQuery
          }
        })
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      searchQuery: ''
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the problem. If I click enter in the input, the redirection will work fine to the route with name `tag`. If I click the button, the redirection will try to happen (I will see in browser url the change) but then instantly it will go back to the existing page

Comment: the provided code has no problem. The issue is probably caused by something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you have a `<form>` tag wrapping the button and input. And the `button` click trigger form submission so the page reload and returns to the same page.

Try modifying the click event into `@click.prevent="redirect"`.

`.prevent` will have the effect of `event.preventDefault()` on the click event.

Will delete this answer if using `<form>` is not the reason.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. The form was the issue indeed. `prevent` helped 

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing the error. Maybe check if `this.searchQuery` has a value when you try to redirect with the click event. In either case, I think you are better of using `<router-link />` to redirect your page. If you want the router-link to look like a button then pass `tag='button'` as in this example:

```
<router-link tag='button' :to="{ name: 'tag', params: { tag: this.searchQuery }}"> search </router-link>
```

Comment: Yes that will work. But with that example then the `searchQuery` is empty there is a console log warning